# Backgroundworker memory leak and the "using" statement

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, backgroundworker

We have a program (Form) which uses many backgroundworker threads in many occasions (we cannot reuse them).

We noticed that the memory of the program keeps growing and analyzing this with a memory profiler I've noticed that there are many backgroundworker objects.

I thought that if I use the "using" statement will do the trick and dispose the objects but it doesn't seem to work.

```
using (BackgroundWorker bgwConnectClient = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    bgwConnectClient.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgwConnectClient_DoWork);
    bgwConnectClient.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Any idea??

Comment: unwire the handler, so the garbage collecter can clean up....but then you can't dispose it until it's done its work!

Answer (score 3):

You are having memory leak because your object is hooked to an event. you need to alter your code

```
BackgroundWorker bgwConnectClient = new BackgroundWorker();
bgwConnectClient.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgwConnectClient_DoWork);
bgwConnectClient.RunWorkerAsync();
```

after you have completed the work and bgwConnect is no longer required

do this

```
bgwConnectClient.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(bgwConnectClient_DoWork);
```

Comment: So there is no use in using the "using" statement... Just to make sure - the correct way is to unwire the handler (possibly inside bgwConnectClient_DoWork) and then call Dispose (also in bgwConnectClient_DoWork) ?? Or should it be in the OnComplete?

Comment: yes, there is no use of using  the "using" statement here. when ever you feel that you don't need the event any more. unlink it and dispose your worker. if you dispose without unlinking the event dispose won't dispose of the worker.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
bgw.DoWork -= bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted -= bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
bgw.Dispose();
}

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
//something
}

Comment: I added the following code: void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
bgw.DoWork -= bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted -= bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
bgw.Dispose();
}
When I run it the memory keeps growing as if the backgroundworker is not really disposed... So what is the best way to dispose the backgroundworker? I really need help here....

Comment: unwire the runworker completed as well. And no need to do anything else. GC will take care of all.

Comment: But I wrote a simple Form program which creates a new background worker on each button click (to simulate the problem). I release the event (actually both of them) as stated above (On the OnCompleted) and still each click more memory is allocated and not released. :( What am I missing??

Comment: you need to know one thing here that GC will collect memory when it will feel feasible.

Comment: I know that I am not supposed to call the GC myhself but it doesn't look as if the GC is working... After a entire day the memory stays the same and nothing get freed

Comment: if after the entire day it is not freed up, then there is some issue. And what makes you believe that this is the culprit? there could be other things as well. Try ants profiler.

Comment: Used ANTS to profile the memoey. I see MANY new objects of type System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback. even after a long time they do not get GC...

Comment: The problem was that we used BackgroundWorker which should be used for UI and not for basic threading. Once we moved to use Task() everything was better and there were no memory issues